# When adding an additional sub task to an already created dag in airflow, is there a way to run only the sub task at the previous time?

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver

I want to add a new sub task to an already running dag and make it work.
Since each task processes data based on a logical date, each task must be fully executed after the start date...

But I want to run only the sub task of the already completed date, but I can't find a way.

I don't want to do this because rerunning all previous tasks is wasteful.

Is there any possible way?

thank you!
[image]